# Mono Android: terminate thread in onPause() state

Tags: android, multithreading, thread-safety, xamarin.android

I am running into a strange problem...
My application is meant to do some webservice calls on a separate thread. Once the webservice call is finished, it would navigate user to a different activity.
In the case when user press the home button or exit current activity it should terminate the webservice if the webservice call thread is still running. Hence I put a thread termination method in the OnPause state.

Here is the method block that is running inside the thread:

```
private Thread _webserviceThread;

void WebserviceCallThread(){
    WebRestult result= WebserviceCall();
    if(!result.containsError()){
         RunOnUIThread(delegate{
             transitionToActivityXYZ();
         });
    }
}

void RunThreadAction(){
    _webserviceThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WebserviceCallThread));
    _webserviceThread.Start();
}


protected override void OnPause(){
    if(_webserviceThread != null && _webserviceThread.IsAlive){
        _webserviceThread.Abort();
    }

}
```

After the webservice call is done and begin the transition to another page, It gets to the OnPause state. However, in some strange cases, it would think that the thread is not finished in the OnPause state, even though the activity transition is the last line of the method.

Has anyone ran into this problem before? If so, how did you solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use [`AsyncTask`](http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=T%3aAndroid.OS.AsyncTask) for this kind of thing. Not only does it **abstract** away the explicit thread handling and provide hooks to do everything you want here; it's also a nice way to represent a `unit of work` that can be used from other `activities`.

There's a simple example in [this](http://www.gregshackles.com/2011/04/using-background-threads-in-mono-for-android-applications/) post part way down, but it doesn't use the generic parameters which are quite handy.

Comment: AsyncTask sounds really promising! Which leads me to another question I have... does the Cancel method only cancels whatever is running inside the DoInBackground method block? Or does it also cancels when it gets to do PostExecute?

Comment: As the docs say, after cancelling, _OnPostExecute_ won't be run. If you aren't checking the _IsCancelled_ periodically in _DoInBackground_ and explicitly aborting, it won't actually finish until _DoInBackground_ is done. It's really just a mechanism to prevent the UI action in _OnPostExecute_ from being executed. I think the observable effect will be exactly what you're chasing in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Task Parallel Library, 
It is standard .NET, and with AsyncTask, it is only recommended for tasks that take less than few seconds. see the [Documentation](http://docs.mono-android.net/index.aspx?link=T%3aAndroid.OS.AsyncTask)

> AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds
>   at the most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of
>   time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by
>   the java.util.concurrent

Below is an example for how to use Task Parallel Library, taken from [here](http://www.gregshackles.com/2011/04/using-background-threads-in-mono-for-android-applications/comment-page-1/#comment-2872)

```
private void loginWithTaskLibrary()
{
    _progressDialog.Show();

    Task.Factory
        .StartNew(() =>
            _loginService.Login("greg")
        )
        .ContinueWith(task =>
            RunOnUiThread(() =>
                onSuccessfulLogin()
            )
        );
}
```

Comment: This is also very helpful! Thanks!